User has opted out of using Google Sign In
I am getting an error:

[GSI_LOGGER]: User has opted out of using Google Sign In.

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with an API call in my web application. The API call works perfectly fine when accessed from incognito mode or a new Chrome profile without any extensions. However, when I try to make the same API call from my normal browsing session, it consistently returns a 400 error.
I've thoroughly reviewed the documentation of the API, and I'm confident that I'm using it correctly. However, I'm at a loss as to why the API call is failing in my normal browsing session but not in incognito mode.
Please open this image manually since i don't even have 10 reputation points
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
